# PHP access an object of a class in another class

Tags: php, class, oop

I'm trying to access an object of a class in another extended class.

```
class MainClass{

    protected $theobject;

    function __construct(){
        $this->theobject = new AnotherClass();
    }

}


class TheClass extends MainClass{

    function AnotherFunction(){
        $this->theobject->SomeFunction();
    }

}
```

I'm getting an error on `$this->theobject->AnotherFunction()`. The error is "Call to a member function SomeFunction() on a non-object".

But this works fine:

```
class TheClass{

    protected $theobject;

    function SoemFunction(){
        $this->theobject = new AnotherClass();
        $this->theobject->SomeFunction();
    }

}
```

Is it even legal to do this in PHP?

Pretty much all the code: http://3v4l.org/MaXe6

When i var_dump the $this->theobject in TheClass is comes back as NULL.

Comment: Can you provide the declaration of the class `AnotherClass`? If you're sure it has that function, then it would be perfectly valid to do this.

Comment: Everything in AnotherClass is set to public.

Comment: please learn about dependency injection

Comment: This works as is. Please provide an actual, full example of something failing.

Comment: @deceze the AnotherClass is PDO class. It kinda long.

Comment: Doesn't matter. This works: http://3v4l.org/sQl18 The burden of proof of the opposite is on you.

Comment: @Ameer still, post it

Comment: @RoyalBg, deceze The "AnotherClass" class: http://3v4l.org/rTv5K
I'm trying to access the query function.

Comment: So you have `$this->database = new database('host', 'dbname', 'user', 'pass');` in your constructor, and afterwards `database` is uninitialized variable? Could you paste the other 2 classes in this site too? And also how do you instantiate them

Comment: MainClass has $this->database = new database(DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

Comment: And in TheClass i have a function that's calling the query function.

Comment: We do understand that from the example, but still there's a case that does not init the variable, so we need the whole code. And paste also the page were you do `new TheClass`

Comment: @RoyalBg here you go: http://3v4l.org/MaXe6

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49720/discussion-between-ameer-and-royal-bg)

Comment: @RoyalBg When i var_dump the $this->theobject in TheClass is comes back as NULL.

Comment: I have copied all your code from the 3v4l.org and paste it to a .php file. When I ran the file, I did not get any errors, except undefined constants, but the object itself was done. Also, when I change the constants to my real db credentials and entered a valid query, it does query my database

Answer (score -4):

```
    class TheClass extends MainClass{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function SoemFunction(){
        $this->theobject->SomeFunction();
    }

    }
```

Do the construct method when init the child class.